# php5.6.2 installation with httpd24 ( apache version 2.4.10 ) on centos/rhel

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, php5

using this repo : http://dl.iuscommunity.org/pub/ius/stable/CentOS/6/x86_64/ius-release-1.0-13.ius.centos6.noarch.rpm for php  installation , and for apache i am using amazon linux repo

current version of php :

```
$ php -v

PHP 5.6.2 (cli) (built: Nov  4 2014 10:01:39) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
```

current version of apache :

```
$ httpd -v 

Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Amazon)
Server built:   Jul 30 2014 23:57:26
```

everything is fine upto this level

packages installed for php are :

```
$ yum list installed | grep php

php56u-bcmath.x86_64            5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-cli.x86_64               5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-common.x86_64            5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-devel.x86_64             5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-embedded.x86_64          5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-enchant.x86_64           5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-gd.x86_64                5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-imap.x86_64              5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-intl.x86_64              5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-ldap.x86_64              5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-mbstring.x86_64          5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-mcrypt.x86_64            5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-mysqlnd.x86_64           5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-pdo.x86_64               5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-pear.noarch              1:1.9.5-1.ius.centos6      @ius                 
php56u-pecl-jsonc.x86_64        1.3.6-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-pecl-jsonc-devel.x86_64  1.3.6-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-pgsql.x86_64             5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-process.x86_64           5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-pspell.x86_64            5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-recode.x86_64            5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-snmp.x86_64              5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-soap.x86_64              5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-tidy.x86_64              5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius                 
php56u-xml.x86_64               5.6.2-3.ius.centos6        @ius
```

installed packages for apache  are :

```
$ yum list installed | grep http

httpd24.x86_64                  2.4.10-1.59.amzn1          @amzn-main           
httpd24-tools.x86_64            2.4.10-1.59.amzn1          @amzn-main
```

now when i try to install php-extension for apache named as `php56u.x86_64`

this happens

```
$ yum install php56u.x86_64   
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00     

amzn-updates/latest                                                             | 2.3 kB     00:00     

4361 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check

---> Package php56u.x86_64 0:5.6.2-3.ius.centos6 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-mmn = 20051115 for package: php56u-5.6.2-3.ius.centos6.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.29-1.4.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: httpd-tools = 2.2.29-1.4.amzn1 for package: httpd-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.29-1.4.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-2.4.10-1.59.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd < 2.4.10
--> Processing Conflict: httpd24-tools-2.4.10-1.59.amzn1.x86_64 conflicts httpd-tools < 2.4.10
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: httpd24-tools conflicts with httpd-tools-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
Error: httpd24 conflicts with httpd-2.2.29-1.4.amzn1.x86_64
You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest`
```

Comment: You may need to replace your existing httpd packages httpd-2.2.29-1.4 to resolve this issue, but better way you can build php from source files with your existing httpd binaries to keep your existing httpd safe and untouched.

Comment: @VaibhavPanmand i think httpd2.4 is installed and this extension i am installing requires httpd2.2  thats where conflicts starts  , well i am trying to install php source packages available from http://php.net/releases/

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `php56u` from IUS is for Apache 2.2 not 2.4 which is why it is trying to install `httpd.x86_64 0:2.2.29-1.4` (Apache 2.2.29) and all the associated tools (`httpd-tools.x86_64 0:2.2.29-1.4`).

However, those two will conflict with `httpd24-2.4.10-1.59` that you've installed from the Amazon repository.

Try the [REMI repo](http://rpms.famillecollet.com/) - I believe it has both PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4 for CentOS 6

If it fits the bill, then you'll be wise to remove IUS and Amazon repos and their packages and start again.

If it doesn't work, then some of your options are:

- Find another repo that has Apache and PHP at the versions you require.  I believe Fedora 21 has these.  The problem here is that you could end up with many dependencies being dragged in at which point your system becomes a hybrid CentOS-6 / Fedora-21 installation which could be a monster to administer (as you've found out already).
- Create a [RPM Spec file](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-build-creating-spec-file.html) and either build your own RPM or use a service such as [Copr](https://copr.fedoraproject.org/) to build an RPM for you. Building an RPM means that it will be easier to uninstall at a later date.
- Build PHP 5.6 from source to work with Apache 2.4
- Wait for a repo to update to the required versions.

Comment: yeah i totally agree with you  about different repositories ( amazon and rackspace )  
but i tried other repos as well like epel & remi ... but no luck same result ... php-extension(php56.x86_64) depends on httpd version 2.2.x on these reps as well